# Ubuntu 17.10 Upgrade Broke VMWare Workstation 12.5

Tags: upgrade, vmware, gcc, vmware-workstation, 17.10

Hi after upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10, vmware is now not starting.

I get the message:

```
/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware-modconfig: Relink `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbsd.so.0' with `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1' for IFUNC symbol `clock_gettime'
```

I am aware that there are patches available and I am attempting to apply these and recompile. I have run from the solution at https://communities.vmware.com/thread/571370:

```
cd ~  
#Copy the vmmon source tar ball to your temporary location
cp /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar .   
#Extract the tar ball
tar xf vmmon.tar  

#Download the modified file that mkubecek posted and overwrite the one from the tar ball for VMware Workstation 12.5:
wget -O ./vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/b50848c985f1a6c0a341187346d77f0119d0a835/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c   

#Wrap up the newly modified files into a tar ball replacing the original one
sudo tar cf /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmmon.tar vmmon-only  

#Rebuild the VMware kernel modules
sudo vmware-modconfig --console --install-all  
Failed to get gcc information. 
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3) 7.2.0 ...
```

Unforunately, vmware-modconfig is failing because of a dependency it seems on a particular gcc version. Am I on the right track?
Any help with this issue would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
Thank you Steve, the below has gotten vmware going again. I've included minor correction. Tested and confirmed I could run a virtual machine.

> ```
> sudo su
> ```

```
# do all below as root
cd /usr/lib/vmware/modules/source
tar xvf vmmon.tar 
tar xvf vmnet.tar
wget -O ./vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/b50848c985f1a6c0a341187346d77f0119d0a835/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c
vim vmnet-only/bridge.c
cd vmmon-only/
make
cd ../vmnet-only/
make
cd ..
mkdir /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/misc
cp *.o /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/misc
insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/misc/vmmon.o
insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/misc/vmnet.o
rm /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
vmware-networks --start
exit

# run vmware as normal user
/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware
```

Comment: In general, 3rd party virtualization is going to lag a bit with new kernels and new releases. This seems to affect vmware more than virtualbox. As vmware is closed source you will have to ask them. As a potential alternate - this is why I try as much as possible to use KVM or LXC (although I still feel LXC is not ready for production servers). KVM + spice is very fast (FWIW). With vmware my guess is there will be a work around anywhere from 1-3 days or 3-4 weeks depending on the complexity of the problem.

Comment: The patch you are trying to apply is for resolving a bug with memory handling, not for the problem related to the error message you mentioned. AFAIK there is no solution for that problem yet. There is a bug report on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1715552

Comment: did you able to resolve the issue "Failed to get gcc information. " ?

Comment: Unforunately not, I currently run a script that sudo executes `insmod` and `vmware-networks` commands and then vmware binary as normal user.

Comment: I have Lubuntu 18.04 - the Method from Stephen Wassell didn't work. The solution from tokam - upgrade to VMWare 14 didn't work too - because of the policy from VMWare only to support the newest hardware. The method from John did work - but only if I start the vmplayer as su. Otherwise I will get dependable a message: Row 106: 29487 memory error (memory dump written) "$BINDIR"/vmware-modconfig --appname="VMWaer Player! --ivon="vmware-player"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've managed to get VMWare Workstation 12.5.7 working on Kubuntu 17.10.

In `/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source`:

1. Extract `vmmon.tar` and `vmnet.tar`

   ```
   sudo tar -xf vmmon.tar
   sudo tar -xf vmnet.tar
   ```

   This will create `vmmon-only` and `vmnet-only` directories.
2. Fetch the patched `hostif.c`

   ```
   sudo wget -O vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/b50848c985f1a6c0a341187346d77f0119d0a835/vmmon-only/linux/hostif.c
   ```

   **(note: https://communities.vmware.com/thread/571370 - also contains a similar fix for VMWare Workstation 14)**
3. Edit `vmnet-only/bridge.c`:

   ```
   639c639
   <        atomic_inc(&clone->users);
   ---
   >        atomic_inc((atomic_t*)&clone->users);
   ```
4. Run

   ```sh
   make -C vmmon-only
   make -C vmnet-only
   cp -t /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/misc *.ko
   modprobe -r vmmon
   insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-16-generic/misc/vmmon.ko
   rm /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1
   ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1/libz.so.1  # see https://communities.vmware.com/thread/572259
   vmware-networks --start  # see https://forum.chakralinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=8579
   ```
5. As user:

   ```
   /usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware
   ```

   (to prevent it running `vmware-modconfig`)

Comment: Awesome, Great work Stephen, your answer was extremely easy to follow. I've repeated the steps explicitly, as well as added minor correction for step 8 in my question edit above. Cheers!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I fixed my step 8 too, thanks for the correction. Hope this all persists over reboot...

Comment: Thanks again Stephen, I'm all good provided I start with `/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware`, otherwise vmware reports not being able to find GCC.

Comment: Thanks much for posting!  This got me running again.  Is there any place we can go to see where VMWare is at with providing a fix?

Comment: Workstation 14.1.0 is now released which fixes this problem.

https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/details?productId=686&downloadGroup=WKST-1410-LX

Comment: 14.1.0 but no 12.5.x branch?

Comment: The vmmon-only folder does not exist for me... and so also not the files that should be in there.

Comment: some notes for other users: change *4.13.0-16* to your kernel or use $(uname -r). The **vmmon.o** and **vmnet.o** need to be renamed again to *.ko. 
I did not get the network to start. but vmware-workstation starts.

Comment: This solution only works for me if... I finish the procedure (as root) by doing depmod -a  /etc/init.d/vmware restart then I can restart vmplayer

Answer (score 9):

I have tried approx all other solutions but nothing worked. But these steps worked for me on Ubuntu 18.04, VMware 12.5.9

```
git clone https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules.git
cd vmware-host-modules
git checkout workstation-12.5.9 (change it to your version. it's important)
make && sudo make install
cd /usr/lib/vmware/lib/libz.so.1
sudo mv libz.so.1 libz.so.1.old
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 .
sudo depmod -a
sudo /etc/init.d/vmware restart
```

Reference:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1715552

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1715552/comments/29

Comment: this works great, thanks a ton! I've been looking for a solution to this for ubuntu 18.04 since it came out!

Comment: Can confirm that this works for Ubuntu 18.10, with VMWare Workstation Pro 12.5.9.

Comment: This solution worked for me on Linux Mint 19.2 64bit with vmware workstation pro 12.5.9.

Comment: Also worked on Debian Buster with Workstation 12.5.9.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer by *Stephen Wassell*, if you are still running the VM Workstation 12.5.x version you will need to re-compile your `.ko` for every kernel patch.. which is alot..

You may see this error: (**Invalid module format**)

```
# insmod /lib/modules/4.13.0-31-generic/misc/vmnet.ko 
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/4.13.0-31-generic/misc/vmnet.ko: Invalid module format
```

Here is a tool to keep the kernel modules for the ubuntu-flavor-distros updated after a kernel patch.

https://gist.github.com/shadowbq/5897002b620b093ca7578b5f13c3f3a1

I've also included a simple wrapper`.sh` that you can use a replacement for launching vmware workstation so you can be sure it appropriately loads the vm-network and vm-mon kernel modules everytime.

Note: this script will not expand the 'tar' or 'patch' the source files, this is for automatically recompiling the kernel modules after a kernel patch following the orignal steps by Stephen Wassell.

Answer (score 2):

The bugfix described by: Stephen leads for many to an other bug: "Failed to get gcc information."

The **simplest solution** is to **[download vmware player workstation 14.1](https://my.vmware.com/de/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/14_0%7CPLAYER-1411%7Cproduct_downloads)**.

Installing it **instead of the 12.5 version** solves the issues described above.

To do so just run

```
chmod +x VMware-Player-14.1.1-7528167.x86_64.bundle
sudo ./VMware-Player-14.1.1-7528167.x86_64.bundle
```

And follow the instructions in the graphical installer.

Comment: which requires a license upgrade

Comment: launch using `/usr/lib/vmware/bin/vmware` instead to resolve "Failed to get gcc information"

Comment: I think noncomercially it also works without that license upgrade

Comment: 12.5.9 happens to be the last version that works with CPUs before 2011 that don't have Intel EPT.