# 17.10 compiling vmware

Tags: compiling, vmware, gcc, 17.10

I haven't been able to launch Vmware Workstation since the 17.10 upgrade, I have seen no errors but the most promising fix has been the one I saw here: https://askubuntu.com/a/968429/460918 - but when I get to 
 the compiling step of the proces with `make` on step 4, I get the following error:

```
Using standalone build system.
In file included from geninclude.c:20:0:
compat_autoconf.h:38:13: fatal error: generated/autoconf.h: No such file or directory
 #   include <generated/autoconf.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
<builtin>: recipe for target 'driver.o' failed
make: *** [driver.o] Error 1
root@tower:/usr/lib/vmware/modules/source/vmnet-only# exit
exit
```

I'm pretty sure that the error that's the root of my problems is `code model kernal does not support PIC mode` which having [looked up said error](https://askubuntu.com/a/851747/460918) makes it sound like I'm hosed until there's an update of vmware or I patch vmware's makefile to work with pic mode. I'm hoping that there's a simpleish fix or something else in the works that might solve my problems.

Comment: It's not at all uncommon that support for brand new versions of Ubuntu lags behind in applications like VMWare, where there is relatively little community support. They're focused on enterprise deployments. There are patches you can manually apply (who knows if they'll work for you) but you'd have done best to stick with 16.04 LTS until 18.04 had some time under its belt.

Comment: Not sure how this is a duplicate of that question, I had issues with running the answer, thus my asking about my new problem. If anything this would be something I'd comment on that other question but I lack the rep to comment.

Comment: It looks like you need to install `linux-headers` for your installed kernel: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=autoconf.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=artful&arch=any

Comment: That's what I was missing. Thanks! If you convert that to an answer I'll accept it.