# VMPlayer installer won't start in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, vmware, vmware-player

I'm trying to install VMware Workstation Player on Ubuntu 18.04. It's a fresh installation of Ubuntu, so everything should be OK.
When I try to run the installer, I get this:

```
    ./VMware-Player-14.1.2-8497320.x86_64.bundle 
Extracting VMware Installer...done.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "atk-bridge": /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatspi.so.0: undefined symbol: g_type_class_adjust_private_offset
/tmp/vmis.pepCPk/install/vmware-installer/vmware-installer: line 56:  4030 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) VMWARE_INSTALLER="$VMWARE_INSTALLER" VMISPYVERSION="$VMISPYVERSION" "$VMWARE_INSTALLER"/vmis-launcher "$VMWARE_INSTALLER"/vmware-installer.py "$@"
```

Before you mark this question as duplicate, I have checked a huge number of potential solutions posted here but none of the issues is the same as the one with VMware player with Ubuntu 18.04. 
This happens with versions 7, 12 and 14 of VMware Player.
Can anyone, please, point me in a direction to solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/548557/how-to-install-gail-and-atk-bridge

Comment: When you say `I have checked a huge number of potential solutions`, well you might have missed one unless we see some list of some kind, else it's a dup

Comment: What worked for me: [link] (https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-vmware-workstation-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)
I didn't try the solution you suggested because this already solved it. I don't know what the issue is but if I install from the vmware.bin file it works, whereas using the bundle throws the errors I posted before. Thanks anyway for your comments.

Comment: Sorry I'm late to the party, but this is it ([link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077500/901004)).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I installed it.

Before the Install of the Vmware Player 14 package, let’s install/update newer version of packages and their dependencies by using the command below:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Now we need to Install some dependencies which is required for Vmware Player 14 Installation.

Note: By default these packages and dependencies should already be installed in Ubuntu 18.04, If not then you can install them by following these steps:

First Install build-essential and gcc as shown:

```
sudo apt install build-essential gcc
```

Then install libcanberra-gtk-module as shown:

```
sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module
```

Now run the following commands in the terminal to install VMware Workstation Player 14 on Ubuntu 18.04, and other Ubuntu Derivatives:

```
mkdir ~/vmware
cd ~/vmware
wget -c https://download3.vmware.com/software/player/file/VMware-Player-14.1.3-9474260.x86_64.bundle
```

OR

Download the bundle here:

[VMWare Player 14](https://my.vmware.com/en/web/vmware/free#desktop_end_user_computing/vmware_workstation_player/14_0)

Give the package permissions:

sudo chmod u+x VMware-Player-14.1.3-9474260.x86_64.bundle

Finally, install:

```
sudo ./VMware-Player-14.1.3-9474260.x86_64.bundle
```

As soon as the installer starts, please follow on screen instructions to complete the installation.

Select to accept the terms in the license agreement and then click on Next.

Update on startup; select yes (if you want).

Feedback; select yes or no.

License Key is optional (can be left blank).

Click Install on next screen.

Close when finished.

FOR WINDOWS 10 GUEST

If 3D acceleration cannot be enabled, or you get a warning saying:

```
Hardware graphics acceleration is not available - As a result, this virtual machine may experience very low graphics performance. Follow the instructions provided by your graphics card vendor or Linux distribution in order to update your computer's OpenGL drivers.
```

and

```
No 3D support is available from the host - The 3D features of the virtual machine will be disabled.
```

Edit hidden file [YOUR HOME FOLDER]/.vmware/preferences and look for a line that starts with:

```
mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers
```

If it is not present then you can add it into the file,
BUT
change it to:

```
mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"
```

ALSO THESE LINES ARE NEEDED AND NEED TO BE ADDED:

```
mks.enableDX11Renderer = "FALSE"
mks.enableGLRenderer = "TRUE"
```

This switches the 3D acceleration from the default DX11 to OpenGL.

Now go to [YOUR HOME FOLDER]/vmware/ [name of guest]/ [the] .vmx (file)
open it with gedit (or whatever editor) and add the three lines:

```
mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"
mks.enableDX11Renderer = "FALSE"
mks.enableGLRenderer = "TRUE"
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

when update headers in linux  and have header modules problem follow this tutorial

https://github.com/mkubecek/vmware-host-modules/blob/master/INSTALL

Answer (score 0):

Run it with the `--console` option as a workaround. Check this [link](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188708) for more information.

```
sudo ./VMware-Player-e.x.p-xxxx.architecture.bundle --console
```

Explanation:

```
--console  
Use the terminal for installation.
```

Comment: you forgot to add the link

Comment: My mistake , this is the link https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=188708